# how to fix the values displayed in a confusion matrix in exponential form to normal form

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

While working with my project, I have obtained a confusion matrix from test data as:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cm
```

Output as:

```
array([[1102,   88],
   [  85,  725]], dtype=int64)
```

Using seaborn and matplotlib, I visualized it using the code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

ax= plt.subplot();
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True,cmap='Blues',ax=ax);
# labels, title and ticks
ax.set_xlabel('Predicted labels');ax.set_ylabel('True labels'); 
ax.set_ylim(2.0, 0)
ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix');
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['Fake','Real']); 
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['Fake','Real']);
```

The output obtained is:

[Confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr2M9.png)

The problem is values with 3 digits (here 1102 been displayed as 11e+03)  or above are being displayed in exponential form.

Is there a way to display it in its normal form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `"fmt"` option:

```
cm = np.array([[1102,   88],[85,  725]])

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True,fmt="d",cmap='Blues')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By adding fmt="d" parameter worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, I recommend using directly the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay

ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_estimator(yourclassifier, X1_test, y1_test,values_format='d', cmap='Blues')
plt.title('Confusion matrix: Decision Tree Classifier (oversampled train set)')
plt.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
plt.grid(b=None)
plt.show()
```